# Change value of an xml tag using java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following `xml` format:

```
<component>
   <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
      <value unit="mm[Hg]" value="120.0" xsi:type="PQ"/>
  </observation>
</component>
```

I want to change value `"120.0"` to `"120"`. Thus, remove the decimal part using `java` code.

Currently, my code is the following but it's incomplete.

```
    NodeList nodePhysical = dom.getElementsByTagName("observation");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodePhysical.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodePhysical.item(i);

        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();

    }
```

Comment: Look at the ``setAttribute`` function in ``org.w3c.dom.Element``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    NodeList nodePhysical = dom.getElementsByTagName("observation");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodePhysical.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodePhysical.item(i);
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    Element ele;
    for (int count = 0; count < childNodes.getLength(); count++) {
    ele= (Element) childNodes.item(count);
    ele.setAttribute("value",ele.getAttribute("value").split("\\.")[0]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is `nodeList`? And where do I have this? Within the `for-loop` that I already have?

Comment: Thanks. Also, attribute "id" does not exist. Where do I have to locate this code? Within my other `for-loop`? Can you please write the full code, including what you need from my current code please?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Srinivasan Sekar for your help!

I fixed it.

My new code is:

```
    NodeList nodePhysical = dom.getElementsByTagName("observation");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodePhysical.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodePhysical.item(i);
        NodeList nodeC = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < nodeC.getLength(); j++) {
            if(nodeC.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element element = (Element) nodeC.item(j);
                element.setAttribute("value", (element.getAttribute("value").split("\\.")[0]));
            }
        }
    }
```